# Continuous state reduction with Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

Let's say I have two event types (`A` and `B`) and `Flux`es that generate them somehow:

```
Flux<A> aFlux = ...;
Flux<B> bFlux = ...;
```

and also a type that holds the current state denoted by type `S`:

```
class S {
  final int val;
}
```

I want to create the following:

```
final S sInitial = ...;

Flux<S> sFlux = Flux.merge(aFlux, bFlux)
  .scan((a, e) -> {
    if(e instanceof A) {
      return mapA(a, (A)e);
    } else if(e instanceof B) {
      return mapB(a, (B)e);
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("invalid event");
    }
  })
  .startWith(sInitial);
```

where `sCurr` is the instance of `S` that was last outputted by sFlux, starting with `sInitial` and `mapA` / `mapB` return the new value of type `S`. Both `S` and `sInitial` are immutable.

That is, I want to:

- Continously output the latest state ...
- ... that is being generated ...
- ... based on the current state and the received event ...
- ... as prescribed by the mapper functions

Is there a way to reorganize the above stream flow in some other way, especially in order to avoid using `instanceof`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add interface and implement it for your A and B classes

```
interface ToSConvertible {
    S toS(S s);
}
```

Now you could use `reactor.core.publisher.Flux#scan(A, java.util.function.BiFunction<A,? super T,A>)` method:

```
Flux<S> sFlux = Flux.merge(aFlux, bFlux)
        .scan(sInitial, (s, e) -> e.toS(s));
```